# How to set jQuery datapicker current date to input tag value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to set a value to input tag on which I create a datepicker. When datepicker is initialized I want to set it. Here is an some pseudo example what I want:

HTML:

```
<input id="test" value=""></input>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#text').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
var currentDate = $('#text').datepicker('getDate');
$('#text').val(currentDate.format('dd.mm.yy'));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set a default date for the datePicker plugin, you might want to use the defaultDate option.

Extract from [JQuery UI/datepicker docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker):

**defaultDate: Date, Number, StringDefault:null**
Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

**Code examples**
Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

Get or set the defaultDate option, after init.

```
//getter
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );
//setter
$(".selector").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

All this you can easily find in the JQuery docs found here: http://docs.jquery.com